# Koin Android: org.koin.error.NoBeanDefFoundException when Inject Repository

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, koin

I make project with mvvm pattern with koin for DI, but i always have No definition found repository

I alredy define repository in module app before viewmodel, but i get some error

Gradle app

```
// Koin for Android
implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$rootProject.koin_version"
// Koin Android Scope features
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:$rootProject.koin_version"
// Koin Android ViewModel features
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$rootProject.koin_version"
```

module

```
val dataModule = module {
//remoteData
single { AppRemoteData() }

//repository
single{ AppRepository(get()) as AppDataSource}

// viewmodel
viewModel{ ListHomeViewModel(get()) }
viewModel { LoginViewModel(get()) }
```

define module

```
val myAppModule = listOf(appModule, dataModule)
```

in app

```
startKoin {
        androidLogger(Level.DEBUG)
        androidContext(this@MainApp)
        modules(myAppModule)
    }
```

Repository class

```
class AppRepository(val appRemoteDataSource: AppRemoteData) : AppDataSource {

override fun loginAccount(email: String, password: String) : LiveData<String> {
    val data = MutableLiveData<String>()
        appRemoteDataSource.loginAccount(email,password,object : AppDataSource.LoginCallback{
            override fun onSucces(id: String?) {
                //berhasil
                data.postValue(id)
            }

            override fun onFailed(message: String?) {
                data.postValue(message)
                d(message)
            }

            override fun onFailure(message: String?) {
                data.postValue(message)
                d(message)
            }

        })
    return  data
}
```

AppRemoteData

```
class  AppRemoteData  {
val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user")
var auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

 fun loginAccount(email: String, password: String, callback: AppDataSource.LoginCallback) {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            task ->
            if(task.isComplete){
                callback.onSucces(task.result?.user?.providerId)
            }else{
                callback.onFailed(task.exception?.localizedMessage)
            }
        }
}}
```

here error message

[image]

Comment: could you post your `LoginViewModel` code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if in your ViewModel has an interface as parameter.

```
class MyViewModel(val interfaceName: InterfaceName) : ViewModel()
```

In your module definition use **singleBy<>** Instead of Single().

```
singleBy<InterfaceName,InterfaceNameImplementation>()
```

Finally in for your ViewModel

```
viewModel { MyViewModel(get()) }
```

This worked for me in Koin 2.0

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that Koin couldn't create a `LoginViewModel` instance for you, because it would've had to provide an instance of `AppRepository` during its creation, but you didn't tell it how to do that.

My guess is that you've accidentally used the `AppRepository` type in the `LoginViewModel` constructor directly, instead of using your `AppDataSource` that you've bound the repository instance to in your module.

So if you have something like this, that would require an `AppRepository` specifically:

```
class LoginViewModel(val dataSource: AppRepository) : ViewModel()
```

You should replace it with this, where you're only asking Koin for an `AppDataSource`, which you did configure it to be able to provide:

```
class LoginViewModel(val dataSource: AppDataSource) : ViewModel()
```